# wkhtmltopdf in PHP - problem with splitting table into pages

Tags: php, html, css, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using wkhtmltopdf and mikehaertl PDF plugin in PHP to generate PDFs.

I have troubles properly splitting tables in PDF. In the picture below, I want that rows can be splitted in the middle, without moving them to another page. It's totally ok for me to have text splitted across two pages:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7y8I.png)

Here's the HTML/PHP code to generate that table:

```
<div style="page-break-before: always;">
    <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
    <?php foreach ($document->areas as $area): ?>
        <table style="page-break-after: always;">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="font-weight: bold; background-color: lightblue;">
                    <?= $area->lorem_ipsum ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <?php foreach ($area->fields as $field): ?>
                        <table>
                            <tr style="background-color: lightgrey;">
                                <td><?= $field->lorem_ipsum ?></td>
                                <td><?= $field->lorem_ipsum ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <strong>lorem_ipsum:</strong><br>
                                    <?= nl2br($field->lorem_ipsum) ?>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <strong>lorem_ipsum:</strong><br>
                                    <?= nl2br($field->lorem_ipsum) ?>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table><br>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

I have tried with different combinations of `page-break-inside` on parent and child elements

Comment: Well, I didn't found exact soultion, but I found workaround, making table using `<div>` elements. Setting `display: flex;` and `flex-direction: column;` for `.table` element and `display: flex`, and `flex-direction: row` on `.row` element.

Works just fine with wkhtmltopdf.